# Issue while creating new records in database + MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables PartyRole and PartyRoleType in database whose models in application are:

PartyRole:

```
 public partial class PartyRole : ILockable, IAuditable, IOverTime
{
    /*** Construtor(s) ***/
    public PartyRole()
    {
    }

    public PartyRole(PartyRoleType obj)
        : this()
    {
        PartyRoleType = obj;
    }

    /*** Public Members ***/
    [Key, Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int PartyRoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PartyRoleTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PartyId { get; set; }


    /* IOverTime */
    [Required, Display(Name = "From")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset FromDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Thru")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ThruDate { get; set; }


    /* Navigation Properties */

    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign key to PartyRoleType: PartyRoleTypeId
    /// </summary>
    public virtual PartyRoleType PartyRoleType { get; set; }
}
```

PartyRoleType:

```
public partial class PartyRoleType : ILockable, IAuditable, IEntity
{
    /*** Construtor(s) ***/
    public PartyRoleType()
    {
        PartyRoleTypePartyRoles = new List<PartyRole>();
    }


    /*** Public Members ***/
    [Key, Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int PartyRoleTypeId { get; set; }


    /* IEntity */
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string NameInUse { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    /* Navigation Properties */

    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign key from PartyRole: PartyRoleTypeId
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<PartyRole> PartyRoleTypePartyRoles { get; set; }
}
```

We are using unitofwork and repository patterns to talk to database.

I will show a screen (MVC view basically) to create a new party role or to edit eixsting party role.

Take the scenario of creating a new party role. I will fill the FromDate & ThruDate and I will choose the PartyRoleType that it will belong from the PartyRoleType dropdown and will click on save.

I am getting an error that PartyRoleType Caption, NameInUse etc., are required. I removed the required data annotation from PartyRoleType Model because any ways we dont fill Type tables from UI.

That error is gone, however I am getting another error it cannot insert nulls into caption nameinuse etc.,

Basically what is happening is If I am trying to create a new PartyRole, the unitofwork is trying to create records in PartyRoleType as well. 
I think it is trying to create records in all its childs also which should not happen.

Can somebody please advise how to handle this or am I doing anything wrong here?

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PartyRole obj)
    {
        obj.Party.PartyId = obj.PartyId;
        obj.PartyRoleType.PartyRoleTypeId = obj.PartyRoleTypeId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PartyRoleRepo.Create(obj);
            UnitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.PossiblePartyRoleTypes = PartyRoleTypeRepo.All();
            ViewBag.PossibleParties = PartyRepo.All();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Code that populates PartyRoleTypes:

```
<div class="l">
PartyRoleType
@(Html.DropDownListFor(O =>
    O.PartyRoleTypeId,
     ((IEnumerable<PartyBiz.Models.Objects.PartyRoleType>)ViewBag.PossiblePartyRoleTypes)
        .Select(OPT =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = (OPT == null ? "None" : OPT.Caption),
                Value = OPT.PartyRoleTypeId.ToString(),
                Selected = (Model != null) && (OPT.PartyRoleTypeId == Model.PartyRoleTypeId)
            }
        ),
        "Choose...",
        new { @class = "combo"}
    )
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.PartyRoleTypeId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need pass null to the PartyRoleType property of PartyRole for not to create childs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert some dummy PartyRoleTypes into the database? It seems like you are trying to insert the cart before the horse (unless I am misunderstanding - do you have data in PartyRoleType?). On your PartyRole class you have:

```
[Required]
public int PartyRoleTypeId { get; set; }
```

So there MUST be at least one PartyRoleType defined. As to why its trying to insert one for you I am unsure - but when I have a relationship like this - I always insert some dummy types to reference.

Moving on, after your comments I see this is not the issue.

What is going on here:

```
obj.Party.PartyId = obj.PartyId;
obj.PartyRoleType.PartyRoleTypeId = obj.PartyRoleTypeId;
```

obj is of type PartyRole, in your PartyRole class I see no definition for Party. So how are you setting obj.Party.PartyId? Is the PartyRole class passed into your Action method some view model?

Comment: I have so much data in PartyRoleType. Caption from PartyRoleType, I am showing it in mvc view in a dropdown so that user can pcik a type for the partyrole that he is creating. PartyRoleTypeId is a foreign key in PartyRole. We definetely do not insert any dummy data in PartyRoleType because creating new types is a different process. We get list of allowed types from customer and we update those tables differently. Here something to do with Unitofwork.Save(), We dont always want this to create a child records, that is wrong!!!

Comment: Yes it is most definitely wrong :). That is odd then, I am afraid I misunderstood. Can you show the code that populates the PartyRoleType drop down?

Comment: The PartyRole class passed into controller is the entire PartyRole model object. You can ignore the line -obj.Party.PartyId = obj.PartyId;, this is added because Party is another child of PartyRole. The reason why I am updating obj.PartyRoleType.PartyRoleTypeId = obj.PartyRoleTypeId; is - the partyrole object has child object partyrole and it's partyroletypeid is null and unitofwork was raising referential integrity constraint error so I have updated partyroletypeid explicitly.